# Simple Voip server for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, voip

I have a network that connects 2 households and would like to setup a simple VoIP server so that I can call between the houses.

It needs to be for Ubuntu, I have used the free 3CX system and while it works brilliantly it doesn't support Linux and I can get a windows box.

The users will never need to call external lines. They will only make 'calls' between laptops/PC.

Can someone please make a recommendation and maybe even a tutorial that I can follow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use asterisk with only SIP or IAX2 protocolos.

apt-get install **asterisk** 
vim /etc/asterisk/sip.conf <--- add users here
vim /etc/asterisk/extensions.conf <--add dialplan here

so basic setup: add user to sip.conf with field

```
[user1]
.....
context = mydialpan
.....
[user2]
.....
context = mydialplan
.....
```

Then edit extensions.conf like:

```
[mydialplan]
exten => 1001,Dial(SIP/user1)
exten => 1002,Dial(SIP/user2)
```

then connect with some softphone like xlite/ekiga to asterisk and dial 1001 or 1002 to connect with correct user.

here is some useful link http://hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Install-Asterisk-on-Ubuntu-Setting-up-Asterisk-PBX

Comment: Thanks this is perfect , its exactly what i wanted minus the bulk , i would give this answer more rep if i could.

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-asterisk-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 2):

With the latest Ubuntu desktop and Empathy, you should be able to do chat/voice/video in the local network without any server, by creating a "People nearby" account.

Alternatively, I suggest creating a Jabber/XMPP server, and look for a cross-platform (or not, depending on your needs) client that has Voice support.

Here is the official documentation of Ubuntu Server to install jabberd2.

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/jabberd2-server.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Skype or another application of that type?

Answer (score 0):

3CX now is available for Linux:
http://www.3cx.com/blog/releases/linux-pbx-google-cloud/

Either try this or Brekeke Sip Server [I love this sip server!]
Linux Installation on Puppy Linux 4.3.1 [Similar on Ubuntu]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcUIPqEVgsE